# Where to Start Flutter Backend Development?

Tags: json, firebase, http, flutter, flutter-web

I am new to flutter and programming as well.
I am following flutters official docs and have sailed smoothly till State Management.
After that it has section for networking https and json serializing.
[here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/networking)

I have no idea about backend and networking and json please help me or guide me how to connect and access servers for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry!
First, you need to learn a bit of JSON and Rest API

Here is a random tutorial

> https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/

Hope it's good) or google it yourself "what is JSON rest API"

What you need to know that there is no "Flutter specific backend" there is an app and the server and most popular way to communicate is Rest API.

Second, you will need to learn How to send a request and receive a response from the server. Hope its in your tutorial and after understanding what is Rest API and JSON it will make sens to you.

But there are great flutter official docs about that

> https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Finally [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup) It's wonderful, thanks to google for it, it provides you a server for your app for free (at least when there are no too much of real users), It will save you a lot of time and money because it provides easy to use free servers that require minimum knowledge of backend

Answer (score 0):

you can start with with packages for basic http request : `https://pub.dev/packages/http`